# How to transform tabular data to image data for analysing using computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply computer vision techniques for tabular data. So, first of all I want to convert the tabular data into image data set. I need help to identify the possible ways to convert it.

Dataset:

| User. | f1. | f2. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 0 | 1 |
| Two | 0 | 1 |
| three | 1 | 0 |
| fourth | 0 | 1. |
| fifth | 1 | 0. |

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper titled [DeepInsight: A methodology to transform a non-image data to an image for convolution neural network architecture](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-47765-6) where the author proposed an approach to transform tabular data to image and applied CNN architectures.

[Here](https://github.com/nicomignoni/tab2img) is an easy implementation of the paper which has been released as a package named tab2img.

Use `pip install tab2img` to install the package. And use it as the following example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_covtype
from tab2img.converter import Tab2Img

dataset = fetch_covtype()

train = dataset.data
target = dataset.target

model = Tab2Img()
images = model.fit_transform(train, target)
```